# Get first div within a div

Tags: jquery

I have the first div as a variable , and am trying to change the inner div's id.

I get uiID like so

```
uiID = $(ui.draggable).attr("id");

$(uiID + "div:first").attr('id','dropped1');

<div id="a">
    <div id ="b">
    </div>
</div>
```

For some reason this is not working. I've tried first() as well

```
$(uiID ).first().attr('id','dropped1');
```

Comment: What is the value of `uiID`?

Comment: Because you have more than 1 div with this ID.

Comment: You cannot reliably change an element's ID across browsers. Add/remove classes instead.

Comment: If uiID = "test", then your selector will be: "testdiv:first". That's not going to work.

Comment: Instead you should add/remove a class... id's are unique.

Comment: @Barmar it's 'div999883833838' that's the format.  I'm getting it through jquerUI

Comment: Then you need to put `#` before it to use it as a selector, and you need to put a space between it and the next div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var uiID = $(ui.draggable).attr("id");

$("#" + uiID + "> div:first-child").attr('id','dropped1');
```

I think this is the only correct solution.

You need the hash for an ID, then you want the **direct descendants** (`>`) and of those the first child.

Answer (score 2):

You just forgot the space:

```
$(uiID + " div:first").attr('id','dropped1');
```

This should be ok.

Oups may be you forgot also # :

```
uiID = "#" + $(ui.draggable).attr("id");
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mZZjc/

Comment: How do you know `uiID` is a string?

Comment: What else could it be to be concatenate to  a string ? If it was a n elment the code would be : var mydiv = $("#a");
$("div:first", mydiv).attr('id','dropped1');

Comment: How do you know the asker doesn't realize you can't concatenate an object with a string and make a valid selector? I know I've answered that question before.

Comment: Given the asker's clarification, it appears that it is a string, and you are probably correct!

Comment: Thank you guys , for some reason I still can't get it to work... -_-

Comment: May be I see your issue you forgot # uiID = "#" + $(ui.draggable).attr("id");

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use:

```
$('div div:first-child');
```

**Reference:**

http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

Comment: Can't use it within the context.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
uiId.find('div:nth-child(1)').attr('id','dropped1');
```

Comment: You *can*, but you shouldn't. `first-child` is definitely preferable to `nth-child(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `#` before the ID and the space between elements in the selector. It should be:

```
$("#" + uiID + " div:first").attr('id','dropped1');
```

or:

```
$("#" + uiID).find("div:first").attr('id','dropped1');
```